# Trouble with set text and image elements and Page Breaks when Using setassign/fpdf with setassign/fpdi

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I'm working on a project where I need to dynamically place elements onto a PDF page fetched from a URL using setassign/fpdf and setassign/fpdi. I have a JSON structure defining the elements' coordinates, sizes, and other properties, and I'm using the provided code to inject these elements into the PDF. However, I'm facing two main issues:

Incorrect Element Placement: The elements are not being placed accurately at the specified coordinates. Despite providing precise coordinates in the JSON, the elements seem to be displaced on the generated PDF.

Missing Page Breaks: It appears that page breaks are not being properly handled. I expected the elements to be injected onto specific pages, but there's no clear distinction between pages, and the elements are not aligning correctly with the intended pages.

Here's a snippet of the JSON structure I'm working with:

```
{
    "file_path": "https://www.sldttc.org/allpdf/21583473018.pdf",
    "elements": [
        {
            "element_type": "text",
            "meta": {
                "cord": {"x": 434.36, "y": 755.01},
                "page": 1,
                "value": "Text Here",
                "area": {"height": 32.57, "width": 101.37},
              
                "img_src": ""
            }
        },
        // ... (more elements)
    ]
}
```

And here's a portion of the PHP code I'm using:

```
protected function deedDownload(int $deedId): BinaryFileResponse
    {

        $deedFileUrl = $request->file_path;

        // Download the remote PDF to a temporary local file
        $tempPdfFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'file_');
        $tempPdfContent = file_get_contents($deedFileUrl);
        file_put_contents($tempPdfFilePath, $tempPdfContent);

        // Create a new FPDI instance
        $pdf = new Fpdi('P', 'pt' );

        // Get the total page coFpdiunt of the PDF
        $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($tempPdfFilePath);

        // Iterate over pages and elements
        for ($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber <= $pageCount; $pageNumber++) {

            $this->injectElementsOnPage($pdf, $deed_elements, $pageNumber);
        }
        // Generate a unique file name for the modified PDF
        $modifiedFileName = 'modified_deed_'.uniqid().'.pdf';

        // Save the modified PDF to local storage
        $modifiedFilePath = storage_path('app/'.$modifiedFileName);
        $pdf->Output($modifiedFilePath, 'F');

        unlink($tempPdfFilePath);

        return $this->download($modifiedFilePath);
    }

    private function injectElementsOnPage(Fpdi $pdf, Collection $deed_elements, int $pageNumber): void
    {

        $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNumber);

        $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);


        $pdf->AddPage($size['orientation'], [$size['width'], $size['height']]);

        $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

        $elementsOnPage = $this->getCurrentPageElement($deed_elements->toArray(), $pageNumber);
        foreach ($elementsOnPage as $element) {

            $this->addElementByType($pdf,$element['element_type'], $element);
        }
    }

    public function getCurrentPageElement(array $elements, int $pageNumber): array
    {

        return array_filter($elements, function ($element) use ($pageNumber) {

            $element = json_decode($element['meta'], true);

            return $element['page'] == $pageNumber;
        });
    }

    public function addElementByType(Fpdi $pdf, string $element_type, array $element_meta): void
    {

        $element_data = json_decode(($element_meta['meta']), true);

        $x = $element_data['cord']['x'];
        $y = $element_data['cord']['y'];
        $width = $element_data['area']['width'] ?? '';
        $height = $element_data['area']['height'] ?? '';

        $element = new Element($pdf);

        if($element_type == 'text')
        {


            $this->pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

$this->pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
$this->pdf->MultiCell(
    $width,
    $height,
    $text,
    1,
    'C',
    false
);
        }
    }

    public function download(string $modifiedFilePath): BinaryFileResponse
    {

        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($modifiedFilePath);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="modified_deed.pdf"');

        return $response;
    }
```